# Clique em modal com a biblioteca Puppeteer Node Javascript

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, automatização, testes-automatizados

Olá,  gostaria de ajuda para conseguir selecionar um item dentro de um mondal, usando a tecla TAB dentro de um FOR em seguida de um ENTER consigo resolver , o problema e quand o o cliente tem mais um contrato, mesmo selecionado pelo id ou campo da tabela.

```
await page.waitForSelector('#ctl00_cph_FIJanela1_FIJanelaPanel1_grvHomo');
await page.click('#ctl00_cph_FIJanela1_FIJanelaPanel1_grvHomo');



await page.waitForSelector('#ctl00_cph_FIJanela1_FIJanelaPanel1_grvHomo > tbody > tr.normal > td:nth-child(1)');
await page.click('#ctl00_cph_FIJanela1_FIJanelaPanel1_grvHomo > tbody > tr.normal > td:nth-child(1)');
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [(CLICK MODAL WITH PUPPETER NODE JS ) CLICAR NO MODAL COM PUPPETEER USNADO NODE JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/402399/click-modal-with-puppeter-node-js-clicar-no-modal-com-puppeteer-usnado-node-j)

Comment: Sua descrição não está clara. Infelizmente não sabemos o que é "contrato" no seu caso, não sabemos como é a tela, nem a estrutura do `HTML`, além disso não temos como testar o seu problema para propor uma solução. O que você pode fazer é criar uma página com um pequeno exemplo que reproduza seu problema para que possamos verificá-lo e te auxiliar, senão temo que seja impossível responder ao seu questionamento

Answer (score -2):

Está difícil de decifrar o que tu quer com a pergunta, porém vou tentar dar uma ajuda simples que talvez ajude já que estás iniciando.

Existe uma extenção do chrome que te da o valor do seletor css, isso de uma maneira mais rápida, o [copy-css-selector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-css-selector/kemkenbgbgodoglfkkejbdcpojnodnkg) ele irá adicionar o campo Css Path ao seu DevTools.

Sabendo exatamente qual o seletor, tu consegue fazer os testes no DevTools, por exemplo, pode testar se o click irá funcionar ou se conseguirá setar algum valor,

Se no console tu colocar:

```
document.querySelector("input[name='q']").value = "teste";
```

a barra de pesquisa do stackoverflow ficará com o texto "teste",
para reproduzir isso no Puppeteer tu coloca assim:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
      document.querySelector("input[name='q']").value = "teste";
}).catch(error => { console.log(error) });
```

Atente-se com sites que possuem Frames, pois não é possível acessá-los dessa maneira com o Puppeteer.

Se quiser especificar melhor sua pergunta, ficará mais fácil te ajudar, boa sorte!